# How to convert T-SQL Script to CTE for Snowflake / DBT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression, dbt

I'm having trouble converting my TSQL Script into CTE that needs to be run on Snowflake through DBT model.

```
declare @i integer = 1
declare @LastID varchar(38) = ''

declare @Change money
declare @ID varchar(38)
declare @TranTypeID varchar(38)

declare @RunningLateFees money = 0
declare @RunningOtherFees money = 0
declare @Temp money = 0

select @ID = ID, @TranTypeID = TranTypeID, @Change = Change from Transactions where Seq = @i
while @ID is not null
begin
    if @ID <> @LastID 
    begin
        set @LastID = @ID
        set @RunningLateFees = 0
        set @RunningOtherFees = 0
    end

    if @Change > 0
    begin
        if @TranTypeID in ('Type1', 'Type2') 
            set @RunningLateFees = @RunningLateFees + @Change
        else 
            set @RunningOtherFees = @RunningOtherFees + @Change
    end
    else
    begin
        set @Temp = @RunningLateFees
        set @RunningLateFees = case when @RunningLateFees > abs(@Change) then @RunningLateFees + @Change else 0 end
        set @Temp = @Change + (@Temp - @RunningLateFees)
        set @RunningOtherFees = case when @RunningOtherFees > abs(@Temp) then @RunningOtherFees + @Change else 0 end
    end

    update Transactions set LateFees = @RunningLateFees, OtherFees = @RunningOtherFees where Seq = @i

    set @i = @i + 1
    set @ID = null
    select @ID = ID, @TranTypeID = TranTypeID, @Change = Change from Transactions where Seq = @i
end
```

When I started out initally, I converted this into a macro within my DBT project.

```
{% macro update_transactions() %}
    
execute immediate $$
declare
  sequence integer default 1;
  var_ID varchar;
  var_TranTypeID varchar;
  var_Change varchar;
  var_LastID varchar default '';
  var_RunningLateFees number(38,4);
  var_RunningOtherFees number(38,4);
  var_Temp number(38,4);
  res resultset;
begin
    let counter := :sequence;
    select ID, TranTypeID, Change into :var_ID, :var_TranTypeID, :var_Change FROM {{ this }} where Seq = :counter;
    while (:var_ID IS NOT NULL) do
        IF (:var_ID <> :var_LastID) THEN
            var_LastID := :var_ID;
            var_RunningLateFees := 0;
            var_RunningOtherFees := 0;
        END IF;

        IF (:var_Change > 0) THEN
            IF (:var_TranTypeID IN ('Type1', 'Type2')) THEN
                var_RunningLateFees := :var_RunningLateFees + :var_Change;
            ELSE
                var_RunningOtherFees := :var_RunningOtherFees + :var_Change;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            var_Temp := :var_RunningLateFees;
            var_RunningLateFees := case when :var_RunningLateFees > abs(:var_Change) then :var_RunningLateFees + :var_Change else 0 end;
            var_Temp := :var_Change + (:var_Temp - :var_RunningLateFees);
            var_RunningOtherFees := case when :var_RunningOtherFees > abs(:var_Temp) then :var_RunningOtherFees + :var_Change else 0 end;
        END IF;

        update {{ this }} set LateFees = :var_RunningLateFees, OtherFees = :var_RunningOtherFees where Seq = :counter;

        counter := counter + 1;
        var_ID := NULL;
        select ID, TranTypeID, Change into :var_ID, :var_TranTypeID, :var_Change FROM {{ this }} where Seq = :counter;
    end while;
end;
$$
;
    
{% endmacro %}
```

However, due to Snowflake's implementation of data as micro-partitions in cloud storage, this approach was not recommended and the updates were too slow. It took about 10mins for 1000 records to update.

I went back to the drawing board trying to convert this into a CTE or SQL with Window functions. Haven't really been successful so far in this endeavour.

Greatly appreciate any help here.

This how my data looks like:

| Seq | Change | TranID | TranTypeID | ID | LateFees | OtherFees |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.75 | 97c2a7 | Type3 | b69 | null | null |
| 2 | 25 | ec0620 | Type1 | b69 | null | null |
| 3 | -27.75 | a5a44d | Type3 | b69 | null | null |
| 4 | 2.75 | 8c6b32 | Type3 | b69 | null | null |
| 5 | -2.75 | 97c2a7 | Type3 | b69 | null | null |
| 6 | 2.75 | 010bfe | Type3 | b69 | null | null |
| 7 | 2.75 | 010bfb | Type3 | 73a | null | null |
| 8 | 25 | e499ad | Type1 | 73a | null | null |
| 9 | 2.75 | e6b37e | Type3 | 73a | null | null |
| 10 | 25 | 464e7a | Type1 | 73a | null | null |
| 11 | 2.75 | 4e1b7f | Type3 | 73a | null | null |
| 12 | 25 | 944c75 | Type1 | 73a | null | null |
| 13 | 2.75 | 9e4851 | Type3 | 73a | null | null |
| 14 | 2.75 | 9e485a | Type3 | 73a | null | null |
| 15 | 25 | 436da8 | Type1 | 73a | null | null |
| 16 | 2.75 | 446ce4 | Type3 | 73a | null | null |
| 17 | 25 | 4307e1 | Type1 | 73a | null | null |
| 18 | 2.75 | 164de2 | Type3 | 73a | null | null |
| 19 | -144.25 | bff6c7 | Type3 | 73a | null | null |

Desired Output:

| Seq | Change | TranID | TranTypeID | ID | LateFees | OtherFees |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.75 | 97c2a7 | Type3 | b69 | 0.00 | 2.75 |
| 2 | 25 | ec0620 | Type1 | b69 | 25.00 | 2.75 |
| 3 | -27.75 | a5a44d | Type3 | b69 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| 4 | 2.75 | 8c6b32 | Type3 | b69 | 0.00 | 2.75 |
| 5 | -2.75 | 97c2a7 | Type3 | b69 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| 6 | 2.75 | 010bfe | Type3 | b69 | 0.00 | 2.75 |
| 7 | 2.75 | 010bfb | Type3 | 73a | 0.00 | 2.75 |
| 8 | 25 | e499ad | Type1 | 73a | 25.00 | 2.75 |
| 9 | 2.75 | e6b37e | Type3 | 73a | 25.00 | 5.50 |
| 10 | 25 | 464e7a | Type1 | 73a | 50.00 | 5.50 |
| 11 | 2.75 | 4e1b7f | Type3 | 73a | 50.00 | 8.25 |
| 12 | 25 | 944c75 | Type1 | 73a | 75.00 | 8.25 |
| 13 | 2.75 | 9e4851 | Type3 | 73a | 75.00 | 11.00 |
| 14 | 2.75 | 9e485a | Type3 | 73a | 75.00 | 13.75 |
| 15 | 25 | 436da8 | Type1 | 73a | 100.00 | 13.75 |
| 16 | 2.75 | 446ce4 | Type3 | 73a | 100.00 | 16.50 |
| 17 | 25 | 4307e1 | Type1 | 73a | 125.00 | 16.50 |
| 18 | 2.75 | 164de2 | Type3 | 73a | 125.00 | 19.25 |
| 19 | -144.25 | bff6c7 | Type3 | 73a | 0.00 | 0.00 |

EDIT: The SQL I have built that isn't getting me the result I need:

```
select
        Seq,
        Change,
        TranID,
        TranTypeID,
        ID,
        SUM(IFNULL(LateFees,0)) OVER (partition by ID order by Seq) as RunningTotalLateFees,
        SUM(IFNULL(OtherFees,0)) OVER (partition by ID order by Seq) as RunningTotalOtherFees,
        CASE
            WHEN Change > 0 AND TranTypeID in ('Type1', 'Type2')
            THEN RunningTotalLateFees + Change
            WHEN Change <= 0
            THEN case when RunningTotalLateFees > abs(Change) then RunningTotalLateFees + Change else 0 end
            ELSE 0
        END as LateFees,
        CASE
            WHEN Change > 0 AND TranTypeID NOT in ('Type1', 'Type2')
            THEN RunningTotalOtherFees + Change
            WHEN Change <= 0
            THEN case when RunningTotalOtherFees > abs(Change + RunningTotalLateFees - LateFees) then RunningTotalOtherFees + Change else 0 end
            ELSE 0
        END as OtherFees
from Transactions
Order by Seq
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: could you add both a sample of the data and the desired output?

Comment: agreed that we need to see an example of what you want and/or an explanation of what your last block of SQL isn't getting right.

But based on your "RunningTotalLate" name... you may find a frame clause useful:

`over (partition by ID order by Seq rows between unbounded preceding and current row)`

Comment: @AleixCC updated both the data and desired output.

Comment: @tconbeer Unfortunately, using the frame clause didn't make any difference to the resultset.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Just to confirm, is it needed for us to see any Type2 example? In the sample provided I can't see any.

Comment: @AleixCC "Type1" and "Type2" are essentially the same type of transactions. They are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

There is a circular reference in your SQL, where `RunningTotalLateFees` refers to `LateFees`. You can simplify this quite a bit by using `greatest` to keep `LateFees` nonnegative:

```sql
select
    Seq,
    Change,
    TranID,
    TranTypeID,
    ID,
    SUM(
        case 
            when TranTypeID in ('Type1', 'Type2')
            then Change
        end
    ) OVER (
        partition by ID
        order by Seq
        rows between unbounded preceding and current row
    ) as RunningTotalLateFees,
    GREATEST(RunningTotalLateFees, 0) as LateFees,

    SUM(
        case 
            when TranTypeID NOT in ('Type1', 'Type2')
            then Change
        end
    ) OVER (
        partition by ID
        order by Seq
        rows between unbounded preceding and current row
    ) as RunningTotalOtherFees,
    GREATEST(RunningTotalOtherFees, 0) as OtherFees
from Transactions
Order by Seq
```